# Vim - search for lines with (or without) character at a specific offset from the start of a line

Tags: regex, vim

I want to find all lines where column 78 (the 78th character on the line) is not a space.

Ideally, I'd like to use it like a normal search.

Comment: 78th column is not the same thing as 78th character in a line. In vim, the column is a function of, for starters, your tab width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, leaving as an example in case someone tries this in the future:

If I want to match column "n", I just need to match anything of column "n-1" and then do my criteria for column n. The following expression finds all lines that have column 35 not equal to space.

```
^.\{34}[^ ]
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this pattern:

```
\%78c\S
```

- `\%78c` matches position at column78 (Actually, the column is the byte number thus it's not exactly right for multi-byte characters). Use `\%78v` to match virtual column.
- `\S` matches non-space

Comment: Never saw a need in `\%{number}c` except for some generated patterns (where `{number}` is generated). Column here means “byte offset from newline” and unless your text is ASCII or in some 8-bit encoding you don’t care about byte offset.

Comment: It appears the only plugin I am using `\%{number}c` is the one that is generating color table where I know for sure that byte offset, virtual column and character count have the same value (all characters — spaces).

Comment: How do I combine these so for example, column 78 is a non-space, and column 80 is the letter 'a'. This does not seem to work: \%78c\S\%80ca

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need not what @kev or you suggest: while you correctly find 78’th *character* (with character+diacritics counting for one) and @kev correctly finds 78’t *byte* it looks like you are solving something like “text beyond 78 column border”. If my assumption about your task is true then you should use

```
\%78v\S
```

(`\%{number}v` matches virtual (screen) column). If not, better to use your answer, I never saw a need in using `\%{number}c` except for in some generated patterns.