# Can my substitute replace at a certain column? (*not* search at a certain column)

Tags: vim

I have some text in a file that I'd like to massage to a fixed-width type format.

I know Vim has a cool `\%c` for the search pattern as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985042/vim-search-for-lines-with-or-without-character-in-specific-column).  Anyone know if there's an equivalent kind of thing to use in the *replace string* of a substitute? So I could do some kind of:

```
:%s/ (.*/\%50c\0/
```

and that would nicely take everything after the first ( and move it out to column 50?

I guess I'd need to make an assumption that I'd shift everything to the right of the ( and fill in with spaces.

Yes, I know there's a plug-in from Dr. Chip that does aligning.  That essentially does what I'm hoping to do.  I was hoping for a `:s` option.  Or maybe even possibly macro?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is abusing the `:normal` command and the `|` (that's a `<bar>` not a capital `i`) motion. For example...

```
:%norm! f(50i <C-v><C-[>d49|
```

Or, as you said, with a macro:

```
qq/(<cr>50i <esc>d49|<cr>q999@q
```

Or with `:%s` and `\ze`

```
:%s#\ze(#\=repeat(' ',50-col('.'))
```

In order of increasing key strokes ;-)

Comment: Any chance you can explain the `<C-v><c-[>`? The keys worked for me... well, I use ctrl + q instead of ctrl v.  They worked, but I'm not familiar with the sequence.
Love the other two options too.

Comment: `<C-v>` allows you to insert a literal character. In this case, it's an escape character. So it allows you to leave insert mode from within the `:norm` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can pad replacement by using `\=` and the `repeat` function.

```
:s/(.*/\=repeat(' ', 50 - col('.') + 1).submatch(0)/
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s\=
:h repeat(
:h col(
```