# searching for a particular string on a particular line position efficiently in VIM

Tags: regex, string, search, vim

As all of you know, Vim is an awesome tool for doing things like this. I'm searching for errors in some reporting text. Say for example I'm looking for the string "0000" in the text I would enter the command ":s/0000". By default, it highlights all instances in which that sequence, and I mean all. The good part is I know that, for example, the string begins on the 11th position in each line. 
What I would like to know is there a command in which I can globally search ONLY for the string "0" in which it occurs on ONLY on the 11th position in each line?
I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim - search for lines with (or without) character at a specific offset from the start of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985042/vim-search-for-lines-with-or-without-character-at-a-specific-offset-from-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has some special regular expression atoms for that. For a screen column, there's `\%v`. So, to search for `0000` at exactly column 11, you'd use

```
/\%11v0\{4}
```

There are also variants for less-than (`\%<v`) and greater-than, as well as similar atoms for byte counts and line numbers. See `:help /\%l` and following paragraphs.

Comment: This seems to work really well. I'm still trying to get better with regex and this was definitely a help. Can you tell me where I would go on here to give you proper credit for the answer? I'll do that right away.

Comment: @Galidari Thanks; please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one: You search the regular expression:

- ^ : (start of line)
- .\{10} : exactly 10 arbitrary characters
- 0000 : the string supposed to start at column 11

so what you enter is:

/^.\{10}0000

Comment: This wasn't THE answer but what it did was really interesting. It began highlighting at the first character of the line and then stopped highlighting at the end of the actual string in question. I tried it with several and the way it works seems like it could yield some good things with what I'm doing. Thank you for this.